# MessageKit messages keep switching sides

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, messagekit

I am implementing a Chat between driver and user in a cab app. I am getting the message from API and displaying it in chat but the chat flips depending on the ID of the last msg

[image: when latest message sender is 'pu']

[image: when latest message sender is 'up']

I just want to add the incoming msg on the left side of the screen.

```
import Foundation
import MessageKit

class ChatViewController: MessagesViewController {

    private lazy var loader:UIView = {
        return createActivityIndicator(UIScreen.main.focusedView ?? self.view)
    }()

    @IBOutlet weak var topView: UIView!

    let imageView : UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.image = UIImage(named:"backgroundImg")
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        return iv
    }()

    var userId = NSNumber()
    var providerId = NSNumber()
    var rideId = NSNumber()

    var timer = Timer()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        member = Member(name: "User", color: .headingGold)
        messagesCollectionView.messagesDataSource = self
        messagesCollectionView.messagesLayoutDelegate = self
        messageInputBar.delegate = self
        messagesCollectionView.messagesDisplayDelegate = self


        var topSafeAreaHeight: CGFloat = 0
        var bottomSafeAreaHeight: CGFloat = 0

        let window = UIApplication.shared.windows[0]
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            let safeFrame = window.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame
            topSafeAreaHeight = safeFrame.minY
            bottomSafeAreaHeight = safeFrame.maxY

        } else {
            topSafeAreaHeight = 10
        }

        self.topView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: topSafeAreaHeight, width: self.view.frame.size.width-20, height: 60)
        self.topView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        self.messagesCollectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: topView.frame.maxY, left: 0, bottom: 70, right: 0)
        messagesCollectionView.backgroundView = imageView

        func backgroundColor(for message: MessageType, at indexPath: IndexPath, in messagesCollectionView: MessagesCollectionView) -> UIColor {
            return isFromCurrentSender(message: message) ? UIColor.myGold : UIColor.headingGold
        }
        getChatHistory()
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 6.0, target: self, selector: #selector(getChatHistory), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        view.bringSubviewToFront(topView)
    }


    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(true)
        timer.invalidate()
    }


    @objc func getChatHistory(){


        self.messages = []
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "\(ServiceConstants.baseUrl+ServiceConstants.MD_GET_CHAT)?request_id=\("\(self.rideId)")&user_id=\(self.userId)")! as URL)


        request.httpMethod = "GET"


        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.addValue("XMLHttpRequest", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Requested-With")



        let tokenStr:NSString = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "tokentype") as! NSString
        let accessStr:NSString = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "accesstoken") as! NSString
        let str = NSString(format: "%@ %@", tokenStr, accessStr) as String
        request.addValue(str, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")


        let session = URLSession.shared

        //            self.loader.isHidden = false


        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            //                DispatchQueue.main.async {
            //                    self.loader.isHidden = true
            //
            //                }


            if (error != nil) {
                print(error!)
            } else {
                let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
                print(httpResponse!)
                do {
                    if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
                        print(jsonResult)

                        let messagesArray = jsonResult["messages"] as! NSArray

                         for dictVal  in messagesArray
                         {
                           if let str = dictVal as? [String:AnyObject]
                           {
                            let msg = str["message"] as! String
                            let type = str["type"] as! String
                            self.member = Member(name: type, color: .myGold)


                             let newMessage = Message(
                                member: self.member,
                                 text: msg,
                                 messageId: UUID().uuidString)

                         //   self.messageCallback(newMessage)
                            self.messages.append(newMessage)


                            }
                        }

                        DispatchQueue.main.async{
                            self.messagesCollectionView.reloadData()
                            self.messagesCollectionView.scrollToBottom(animated: true)
                        }

                    }
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }

            }
        })

        dataTask.resume()


    }

    func sendMsg(msg:String){


        let parameters:[String:String] = ["user_id":"\(userId)","provider_id":"\(providerId)","request_id":"\(rideId)","type":"up","message":"\(msg)"]

        let url = URL(string: ServiceConstants.baseUrl + ServiceConstants.MD_SEND_CHAT_MSG)!

        let session = URLSession.shared

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)

        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.addValue("XMLHttpRequest", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Requested-With")


        let tokenStr:NSString = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "tokentype") as! NSString
        let accessStr:NSString = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "accesstoken") as! NSString
        let str = NSString(format: "%@ %@", tokenStr, accessStr) as String
        request.addValue(str, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")


        do{
            request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted)

        }catch let error
        {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

            self.loader.isHidden = false

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {data, response, error in

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.loader.isHidden = true

            }

            print(response as Any)

            guard error == nil else{return}
            guard let data = data else{return}

            do{
               if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String:Any]
                {
                    print(json)

                }
            }catch let error
            {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }




        })
        task.resume()


    }

    var messages: [Message] = []
    var member: Member!


    @IBAction func backBtnAction(_ sender: Any) {
         dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

extension ChatViewController: MessagesDataSource {


    func numberOfSections(
        in messagesCollectionView: MessagesCollectionView) -> Int {
        return messages.count
    }

    func currentSender() -> Sender {
        return Sender(id: member.name, displayName: member.name)
    }


    func messageForItem(
        at indexPath: IndexPath,
        in messagesCollectionView: MessagesCollectionView) -> MessageType {

        return messages[indexPath.section]
    }

    func messageTopLabelHeight(
        for message: MessageType,
        at indexPath: IndexPath,
        in messagesCollectionView: MessagesCollectionView) -> CGFloat {

        return 12
    }

    func messageTopLabelAttributedText(
        for message: MessageType,
        at indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSAttributedString? {

        return NSAttributedString(
            string: message.sender.displayName,
            attributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)])
    }
}


extension ChatViewController: MessagesLayoutDelegate {
    func heightForLocation(message: MessageType,
                           at indexPath: IndexPath,
                           with maxWidth: CGFloat,
                           in messagesCollectionView: MessagesCollectionView) -> CGFloat {

        return 0
    }
}
extension ChatViewController: MessagesDisplayDelegate {
    func configureAvatarView(
        _ avatarView: AvatarView,
        for message: MessageType,
        at indexPath: IndexPath,
        in messagesCollectionView: MessagesCollectionView) {

        let message = messages[indexPath.section]
        let color = message.member.color
        avatarView.backgroundColor = color
    }
}
extension ChatViewController: MessageInputBarDelegate {
    func messageInputBar(
        _ inputBar: MessageInputBar,
        didPressSendButtonWith text: String) {

        sendMsg(msg: text)

        member = Member(name: "up", color: .myGold)


        let newMessage = Message(
            member: member,
            text: text,
            messageId: UUID().uuidString)


        messages.append(newMessage)
        inputBar.inputTextView.text = ""
        messagesCollectionView.reloadData()
        messagesCollectionView.scrollToBottom(animated: true)
    }
}
struct Member {
    let name: String
    let color: UIColor
}

struct Message {
    let member: Member
    let text: String
    let messageId: String
}


extension Message: MessageType {
    var sender: Sender {
        return Sender(id: member.name, displayName: member.name)
    }

    var sentDate: Date {
        return Date()
    }

    var kind: MessageKind {
        return .text(text)
    }
}
```

This is my class for chatViewController and this is my first experience with messageKit. I might be missing something simple or trivial..

Comment: show you have configured your `cellForRowAt`

Comment: @KeshuR. see edit

Answer (score 0):

The main function that determines alignment is,

```swift
func currentSender() -> Sender {
     return Sender(id: member.name, displayName: member.name)
}
```

In this case, `member.name` is the identifier to recognize own messages.

The primary provider of that data is initialized as,

```swift
member = Member(name: "User", color: .headingGold)
```

But as you insert a new message it got changed to causing logic for alignment to change,

```swift
member = Member(name: "up", color: .myGold) // why change global variable?
```

In this case, if a member with `name: "up"` sends a text it switches sides. Better refactor the entire codebase and maintain better id for current and counterpart users.

Follow, [official Doc implementation](https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit/blob/main/Example/Sources/AppDelegate.swift) for reference.